# Grails 4 with spring-security-oauth2-provider:4.0.0-RC1

Tags: spring, grails, oauth-2.0

I created a Grails 4.0.2 application with this plugins:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:4.0.0'
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-oauth2-provider:4.0.0-RC1'
```

I followed the documentation: https://bluesliverx.github.io/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider/v3/manual/index.html

After I'm trying to use the authentication by:

```
curl -X POST \
     -d "client_id=my-client" \
     -d "grant_type=password" \
     -d "username=my-user" \
     -d "password=my-password" \
     -d "scope=read" http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
```

But I receive this error:

```
    URI
/oauth/token
Class
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Message
There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
Trace
    Line | Method
->>  244 | matches                        in org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder$UnmappedIdPasswordEncoder
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    198 | matches                        in org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder
|     90 | additionalAuthenticationChecks in org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
|    166 | authenticate                   in org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider
|    175 | authenticate . . . . . . . . . in org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager
|    123 | attemptAuthentication          in org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter
|    212 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter
|    334 | doFilter                       in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    105 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
|    334 | doFilter                       in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     58 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter
|    334 | doFilter                       in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    215 | doFilterInternal . . . . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy
|    178 | doFilter                       in     ''
|    193 | internalDoFilter .
```

I find this solution:

https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-security-there-is-no-passwordencoder-mapped-for-the-id-null/

but I don't know how apply the solution on the grails project.

Anyone could help me?

Thank you,
 Cristian

Answer (score 1):

I too ran into this issue but I believe I found the answer.

Add this to the Client class that the oauth plugin init script generates:

```
   static mapping = {
       autowire true
   }
```

Or add this to the runtime.groovy to enable service injection to all domain classes by default
grails-app/conf/runtime.groovy

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
        autowire true
}
```

As for the reason this is happneing. The Client Domain class tries to call this code before being inserted:

```
protected void encodeClientSecret() {
        clientSecret = clientSecret ?: NO_CLIENT_SECRET
        clientSecret = springSecurityService?.passwordEncoder ? springSecurityService.encodePassword(clientSecret) : clientSecret
}
```

But it fails to encode the password correctly since the spring security service is null.
The Grails documentation mentions that starting with Grails 3.3.0, services are not longer injected by default in Domain classes and need that mapping to be injected.

Answer (score -1):

I temporary solved my question by setting in the resources.groovy

```
beans = {
    userSecPasswordEncoderListener(UserSecPasswordEncoderListener)
     passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder) {

    }
```